# Unable to load the requested file: projects/project_detail/.php

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to CI, i am passing parameter through view file like,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('projects/project_detail/'.$project_info['project_id']);?>" class="button small">More Details</a>
```

i tried to view the content of specific id through controller.

```
    public function project_detail($id){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['content_for_layout'] = 'projects/project_detail/'.$this->id;
        $data['project'] = $this->project_model->get_project_detail($this->id);  //folder/filename in which data is present.
        $this->load->view('layouts/default', $data);
}
```

`projects/project_detail/1` = where content is present
layouts/default wants to show content in this file.

I'm getting error -

```
Unable to load the requested file: projects/project_detail/.php
```

In route file im have made changes like this

```
$route['projects/project_detail/(:num)'] = "projects/project_detail/$1";
```

help me to open content of id=1 in projects/project_detail

Answer (score 0):

Change this;

```
$data['content_for_layout'] = 'projects/project_detail/'.$this->id;
$data['project'] = $this->project_model->get_project_detail($this->id);
```

To this;

```
$data['content_for_layout'] = 'projects/project_detail/'.$id;
$data['project'] = $this->project_model->get_project_detail($id);
```

Removing "$this" from the id. You are using the ID you've passed to the function, not the ID of the object.

Also, I don't think there's any need for the route you're using.

Comment: Hi Craig,i appreciate for your ans, but the problem is  im calling data of particular id from view as mention above, the dta is stored in project/project_detail in contoller im passing the content store in one page to layouts/default where header, content of file and footer is present.

Comment: Hi craig, i appreciate your reply, but the problem is different, im i want to fetch data of particular id from Db which im calling from view file as mention above, now i have set one folder layout inside which a file named default is present. where header, content(data as a page) and footer is present.now when controller project calls, project_detail function wd id 1 then project/project_detail/id is unable to open in layout/default page . please see the code as mention above.

Comment: in layout/default page the code is like this <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
<!-- header ends -->
<div class="inner_wrapper">
<!-- content starts -->
<?php $this->view($content_for_layout); ?>
<!-- content ends -->

<!-- footer starts -->
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?> , where content_for_layout is a page like project/project_detail/1 to open. kindly help im stucked here.